# How to use error propagation in calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives, error-propagation, linearization

One side of a right triangle is known to be 15 cm long and the opposite angle is measured as $30^\circ$, with a possible error of $\pm 1^\circ$.

(a) Use differentials to estimate the error in computing the length of the hypotenuse. (Round your answer to two decimal places.)

(b) What is the percentage error? (Round your answer to the nearest integer.)

I've tried this several times now but I keep getting it wrong. So I start with $h=\frac{15}{\sin(\theta)}$ and then I used the quotient rule to take the derivative of both sides and multiplied by $d(\theta)$ and I got $dh=\frac{-15\cos(\theta)}{\sin^2(\theta)}*d(\theta)$ but when I plugged in $30$ and $1$. I got the wrong answer. Can somebody tell me how to do this problem? I very frustrated with it.

Comment: What answer did you get? To me it looks like your derivative is right so that in your situation you would have $\frac{dh}{d \theta}=-30 \sqrt{3}$...if $d \theta$ is measured in *radians*.

Comment: I got -51.96, which is the same as -30*sqrt(3) but this answer was wrong.

Comment: Indeed, you need the appropriate modification for degrees, which amounts to either converting $d \theta$=1 degree to radians or computing $\frac{dh}{d \theta}$ in degrees in the first place.

Comment: I'm really confused on what you're saying, I know 30 degrees is pi/6 but using that doesn't give me a different answer.

Comment: If you compute $\frac{dh}{d \theta}$ where $\theta$ is measured in radians with this geometry, you get $-30\sqrt{3}$. But now your $d \theta$ must also be measured in radians. Since the relevant $d \theta$ here is one degree, that's $\frac{\pi}{180}$ radians. You need that correction to get an answer that is not just so big as to be meaningless (seeing as the unperturbed length of the hypotenuse is $30$ cm)...

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.